# Rails - Order videos by comments count

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Video` model and a `VideoComment`one with an association to `Video`.

I am trying to find the **most commented videos**.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implement a counter_cache :

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :video_comments, :counter_cache => true
end
```

You'll have to create an attribute called `video_comments_count` on the `videos` table to make this work. You'll then be able to sort by this attribute.

Rails will automatically increment the counter cache for you on video comment creation and decrement on deletion

Comment: Thanks for the solution :) One more question, in my views, do I show the number of comments using the `video_comments_count` column or do I still use `video.video_comments.count`?

Comment: Always use video_comments_count, it's a field in the DB so very fast to get. If you use video.video_comments.count, you'll send a count request to SQL. This is expensive on large data sets and will give you the same result !

Comment: Ok, because I read somewhere that the count method verifies for a counter cache before tring sql. (the length mehod would give the same result but without even looking for cache

Comment: Oh, you might be right ... I don't know about this, but it's easy enough to test in dev environment. Look at the log file and you'll see if a count is sent to SQL :)